# How to delete fragment onFling gesture Android

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello all In my app I have an activity in which I can add many fragments. Fragments consist of single image view containing 96x96 thumbnail and they are placed in grid layout. What I want is to remove particular fragment when onFling gesture detected.

Here is whatI try. I have

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment
{
    ImageView image;
    GestureDetector mDetector;
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener gestureListener;
    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
        mDetector = new GestureDetector(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),new MyFlingGesture());
        image = new ImageView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());

        image.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                mDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
                return true;
            }
        });


        return image;
    }
    class MyFlingGesture extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.remove(// what to pass here);
            // or what is the other ways?
            return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
        }
    }

}
```

If I test on my phone I am able to detect Fling gesture. How to delete that fragment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your fragments on the backstack, just calling `finish()` would work. In case that you do not put the fragments on the backstack, or you just want to be sure it works use:

First you need to add a `field` to store the active fragment. In your BlankFragment class add

```
public BlankFragment mBlankFragment;
```

In `oncreateview` add

```
mBlankFragment = this;
```

Now you can use this variable in the fling listener using

```
 getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mBlankFragment).commit();
```

---

Another way to do it is to find out what the active fragment is using a function like

```
public Fragment getVisibleFragment(){
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getFragmentManager();
    List<Fragment> fragments = fragmentManager.getFragments();
    for(Fragment fragment : fragments){
        if(fragment != null && fragment.isVisible())
            return fragment;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: but "this" in this context means MyFlingGesture not Fragment